# Debugging LAMP/CakePHP site memory leak?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, cakephp, memory-leaks

I run a site on AWS, built on CakePHP 2.2.3, PHP 5.6.32, and a MySQL database. Recently, I've had problems with server crashes that seem to start when the server runs out of memory.

I've set up CloudWatch to monitor memory usage, and see the following over the last few days (server was reset ~5 days ago):

[image: CloudWatch memory usage log]

Running 'top' on the server produces the same result for memory usage.

This looks like a memory leak to me (is that correct?), but my understanding is that PHP 5.6 is supposed to do garbage collection. I don't use explicit memory allocation in my code at all, but can't rule out the possibility that CakePHP does. And maybe it's no a problem with PHP at all.

I'm new to web development, and am at a bit of a loss on where to start. Google searches come back with solutions to OOM errors due to large allocations, but that's not the issue here. What could cause a site to show an almost monotonically increasing memory usage like this? How should I go about finding the culprit?

*Edit*: Output of 'top' sorted by memory usage below, in case it's helpful.

[image: Output of top]

*Edit 2*: Output of 'atop -m' below.

[image: Output of atop]

Comment: On `top`, which process is eating all the memory up?

Comment: At this point in time there is nothing wrong on a screenshot. To get better historical data use `atop`.

Comment: why "PHP 5.6.32," *kind* of old

Comment: i think cloudwatch does a better job than atop myself

Comment: ishegg: Posted the results from 'top' at the bottom of the question, maybe as you were typing your response. Weird thing is that there doesn't seem to be anything eating up a bunch of memory all on its own.

Comment: zerkms: Added the results from 'atop' to the question above. Not seeing anything not reported in top myself, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @JasonCooper `atop` records stats, so when it happens next time you can get a better picture. At the moment numbers look fine, nothing is wrong with your server.

Comment: @zerkms Just to check, because I suddenly realized that I may have figured out atop's output... Is the screenshot saying that I've got 7.8 GB total of memory, of which 3.3 is outright free, 1.3 is cache, and 2.4 is slab, plus some change, so that only about 0.8 GB (7.8 minus the others) is actually in use?

Comment: @JasonCooper yep, I'd say it's more or less correct.

Comment: @zerkms Looks like I most likely don't have a memory leak at all, then. Thank you for your help -- if you would like to add your comment as an answer (atop is more detailed, shows nothing wrong), I'd be happy to select it as the correct one.

Comment: @JasonCooper if you haven't realised it yet, `atop` writes the history of measurements, so you can see the historical data of how all the numbers changed. Check some article or its documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to connect to a profiling service https://blackfire.io or https://newrelic.com. They have in-depth profiling and logging and can be pretty precise when it comes to resource allocation and which script/module is the culprit.

Short of that, if you have some idea where in your application could be having an issue, you can use strace (https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to attach to your PHP process(es) to view the stack output and execute those scripts/modules.... strace is very handy when debugging a php process.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I went into the Mysql.php code of Cakephp, and set every variable to null after a closeCursor, like:

```
$cols->closeCursor(); $cols = null;
```

This stopped our memory leak and our crashes. It was normally topping at max memory and crashed after a while.